# Repository that depends on account id - is this good approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm somewhat new to DI/IC and I wonder if approach that I'm doing is not some kind of anti-pattern or maybe there is some better way of doing this.

#### Scenario

Api gives details about projects, those details are hidden under accounts. Account gives authorizes to the api and then can get his projects e.g. `/api/v1/projects/`.

Everything lies underneath Account, I don't want to make every method like `GetByAccountId()`. Or for example if Porject has Items. `GetByAccountAndProjectId()`. So basically I want the account to be injected all the time.

#### My approach

```
public class ProjectRepository : IProjectRepository
{
    private readonly IMongoDbContext _db;
    private readonly Account _acc;

    public ProjectRepository(IMongoDbContext db, Account acc)
    {
        _db = db;
        _acc = acc;
    }

    public IQueryable<Project> GetAll()
    {
        return _db.Projects.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.AccountId == _acc.Id);
    }
}
```

And I inject the Account to every repository like so.

```
kernel.Bind<IProjectRepository>().To<ProjectRepository>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("acc", x => Kernel.Get<IAccountAuthorizationService>().GetCurrentAccount());
```

#### Question

- Is this approach any good?
- Is there any better way?
- Isn't it strange that I resolve dependency inside my dependency registration?

Comment: I think it's fine. A benefit is that it decouples the client from the concept of an `Account`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree i think this is fine.
Instead of binding it as constructor argument how about changing it to:

```
kernel.Bind<IProjectRepository>().To<ProjectRepository>();

kernel.Bind<Account>()
      .ToMethod(ctx => x => Kernel.Get<IAccountAuthorizationService>().GetCurrentAccount());
```

That way you don't have to do it for every repository etc. where you need the account.

If the Account is the same for each call to `IAccountAuthorizationService.GetCurrentAccount()` you might even performance-improve it to:

```
Lazy<Account> lazyAccount = new Lazy<Account>(
     () => kernel.Get<IAccountAuthorizationService>().GetCurrentAccount());
kernel.Bind<Account>().ToMethod(ctx => lazyAccount.Value);
```

(but i would only do this if performance of this resolution is really a critical concern).